# Neural network non-linear input

Tags: input, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a question about the input choice for my neural network. I have a geographical area that is split into 40 smaller parts which i wish to give as input to my network. I have labeled those from 0-40 and passed them as ints to the network togeather with some other parameters to find a relation. However the desired result from these area inputs are completely unrelated, so the input area 1 and 2 is just as different as 1 and 25.

Often when i read exammples the input value is quite logical. 0 or 1 if the input is a simple true/false alternative. Or maybe if the image is a 32*32 grayscale picture the input is 1024 neurons accepting values from 0-255.

In my case when the 'area' parameter is not linear, what is the proper method to pass it to my network? Or is the whole setup faulty?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? i.e. what question should your NN answer?

Comment: are they really **completely** unrelated? geographical things usually are related (some objects are closer etc.). If they are completely unrelated one-hot-encoding is a typical way to go.

Comment: I wish to predict the quantity of a certain event occurring for a given hour and geographical area. Based on previous data. They should be almost completely unrelated, their numbering is quite random over the map actually

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend 40 input variables. Every input variable would correspond to exactly one of your 40 areas. You would set only the input variable corresponding to the correct location to ''1'', and all others to ''0''

Comment: That's definitely a possibility yes. Depending on the neural network implementation you use, that should be perfectly feasible computationally. With those time-based parameters you lose information by doing that though, because Tuesday is more similar to Wednesday than Friday for example. You could also normalize those inputs to lie in [0, 1]. For instance, Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1/7, Wednesday = 2/7, etc. I don't think there's a clear-cut answer what's best here though, depends on domain, so should test.